# MySQL order by where greater than a phrase alphabetically?

Tags: php, mysql

How can I do a MySQL select statement to order by name where it's alphabetically greater than *grapes*? * The result should be *orange*.

apple
grapes
orange
pear
pineapple

I can't just do `ORDER BY name`. It would have to be order by name starting after *grapes*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it by using LIMIT 1 and WHERE CLAUSE :

```
SELECT name FROM youtable WHERE name > 'grapes' ORDER BY name LIMIT 1
```